# Where is the Credentials Manager in Win10?

Tags: windows-10, credentials-manager

I'm using a localized (Polish) version of Windows. That means typing 'Credential Manager' in search doesn't turn up anything relevant. I can't spot anything that would match the name in my language in the Windows Settings. All the articles either say 'type in search' or 'find in settings' but without knowing what translation (...certainly not direct because there's nothing matching) Microsoft used I can't guess where it is. Could you provide e.g. a screenshot, detailed guide of which UI elements to click (not depending on English names) or a command - or just the Polish translation which Microsoft happened to apply - to launch it?

(I mistyped my password in TortoiseGit and it remembered it that way and now fails to log into the repository due to having stored invalid credentials and I can't remove them.)

Comment: Do a Win+R on the keyboard (opens a Run box), then type in: certlm.msc, hit ok. This will bring up the certificates for the local machine, if you only want to see certs for current user then type: certmgr.msc

Comment: I managed to delete the bad cert a different way: in command prompt: `cmdkey /list` to show the certs and their identifiers, then `cmdkey /delete:git:http://gitlab....` to delete it.

Comment: You can use [Microsoft Terminology Search](https://msit.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODJmYjU4Y2YtM2M0ZC00YzYxLWE1YTktNzFjYmYxNTAxNjQ0IiwidCI6IjcyZjk4OGJmLTg2ZjEtNDFhZi05MWFiLTJkN2NkMDExZGI0NyIsImMiOjV9) to get the Microsoft version of the technical term. Put "Credential Manager" as Source term and search, then you can get translated term in your language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you provide e.g. a screenshot, detailed guide of which UI elements to click (not depending on English names) or a command - or just the Polish translation which Microsoft happened to apply - to launch it?

Credential Manager is located within the User Accounts within the Control Panel

[image]

Within Control Panel navigate to `Control Panel\User Accounts\` or `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you, found it. The fact the Control Panel is an entirely different entity than Windows Settings didn't help in my search... "Menedżer poświadczeń" - I'd never guess...

Comment: `Credential Manager` has not been ported to the Settings application at this time.

Answer (score 7):

open cmd or Win+R and type

```
control keymgr.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

- this is the Win32 dialog with LM+WWW credentials...
- Still works on Windows 10 2004/19041

if you use it often
create a shortcut in desktop with the name "Credentials"

or a batch file and put it anywhere in "path"

```
echo rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr > credentials.cmd
```